# cannot echo a variable to remote bashrc via ansible

Tags: bash, ansible

Somewhere I am not being able to read / write to ~/.bashrc in remote hosts with Ansible.
I tried, previously with .bashrc and now with .profile but all in vain :

```
- name: install elasticsearch
      command: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "cd /apps/dmg/ && tar -xzf elasticsearch-6.4.3.tar.gz"
        - "cd /apps/dmg/elasticsearch-6.4.3"
        #- echo "ES_HOME=/apps/dmg/elasticsearch-6.4.3" >> ~/.profile
        #- "source ~/.profile"
```

I realised that, ansible task just isnt writing to any file in there at remote hosts, because no "~/.profile" file exists even after running this task, which apparently succeeds :

```
changed: [WONTTELLXXXX] => (item=echo "ES_HOME=/apps/dmg/elasticsearch-6.4.3" >> ~/.profile)
```

Comment: please note that when I tried this, the commands under with_items were uncommented, still it isnt working

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the expansion `~` (citation needed wip)

```
~/.profile
```

Use full path for `remote_user`, `become_user`, or any other if needed. For example

```
"/home/{{ remote_user }}/.profile"
```

`$HOME` might work too

```
"$HOME/.profile"
```

---

Notes

The tasks below would help to find out what is going on

```
- command: whoami
  register: result
- debug: var=result.stdout

- command: pwd
  register: result
  args:
    chdir: $HOME
- debug: var=result.stdout

- command: pwd
  register: result
  args:
    chdir: ~
- debug: var=result.stdout
```